# Algorithm for signal identification

Tags: algorithm, signals, identification

I am getting continuously 100 k data points per second with a signal noise ratio (SNR) about 0.1~1%.
Is there any FAST/REALTIME algorithm to identify these signals?
The simple histogram helps for higher SNR, but not for 0.1%

The plot gives an impression how my data looks like, but with higher SNR.

Thanks for any inputs!!

[image]

Comment: Is your signal constant? Is the change rate limited? The more you know about the signal's and the noise's characteristics, the better algorithm you will be able to develop.

Comment: Another thing to consider: allowing a longer delay between input and decision will give you a longer look-ahead buffer, which can also help in estimating the noise level for each sample.

Comment: Thanks @LiorKogan! My signal is not completely constant, and it appears at any position, ie. anywhere -400 to 400 in my plot. But once it appears it stays more or less. Or I can say for about 30 s it stays somewhere, then it jumps to another area. What do you mean with "Is the change rate limited?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "not too bad" solution now, see result from the attached plot
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X51d8.png)

(1) collect coming points (data or noise) and fill up #1 array;
(2) for the next coming point, check whether there are enough friends (eg. 3; friend means the difference between them smaller a threshold) in #1 array; if yes mark this point as an identified; collect all identified points and fill up in #2 array;
(3) repeat 2nd step but compare with items in #2 array, and then fill up all identified points into #3 array;

I plot all points in #3 array, and it seems that the identification quiet good especially with the help of histogram -- only show the peak.

Plot: left -- original points; middle -- identified points; right -- the peak of histogram.